# changing variable values into new variables in r

Tags: r, variables, data-manipulation

I have a data set with about 600 animals with this structure:

```
anim <- c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2)
point <- c(1,2,3,4,6,3,4,5,6)
temp <- c(38.8,38.5,33.2,33.5,37.2,36.2,36.5,36.0,37.8)
mydf <- data.frame(anim,point,temp)

anim point temp
1     1    38.8
1     2    38.5
1     3    33.2
1     4    33.5
1     6    37.2
2     3    36.2
2     4    36.5
2     5    36.0
2     6    37.8
```

The variable "point" contains different measuring  points (temperature) on an animal and I need to have these measuring points (1,2,3,4,5,6) as new variables such that 1=bel,2=ber,3=le,4=re,5=ey,6=cr. Note, that some points may not appear or measured and therefore NA should be put in.

mynewdf should look like this:

```
anim  bel   ber   le    re    ey    cr
1     38.8  38.5  33.2  33.5  NA    37.2
2     NA    NA    36.2  36.5  36.0  37.8
```

I hope that my question is clear enough and any help would be very much appreciated.

## EDITED:

This is an extract from my actual data set:

head(irpig,n=25)

head(irpig,n=25)
      dam  anim point temp
1  1A0331 20584     1 37.9
2  1A0331 20584     2 37.7
3  1A0331 20584     3 34.3
4  1A0331 20584     4 35.8
5  1A0331 20584     6 37.6
6  1A0331 20585     2 38.7
7  1A0331 20585     4 36.4
8  1A0331 20585     6 38.0
9  1A0331 20586     1 39.0
10 1A0331 20586     2 39.8
11 1A0331 20586     3 37.9
12 1A0331 20586     4 38.0
13 1A0331 20586     6 38.5
14 1A0331 20587     1 39.3
15 1A0331 20587     2 38.9
16 1A0331 20587     3 39.4
17 1A0331 20587     4 38.6
18 1A0331 20587     6 39.4
19 1A0331 20588     1 39.6
20 1A0331 20588     2 39.2
21 1A0331 20588     3 38.9
22 1A0331 20588     4 38.0
23 1A0331 20588     6 39.6
24 1A0331 20589     1 38.1
25 1A0331 20589     2 38.7

Baz

Comment: @Ramnath: It worked when I applied it to the subset of the first 25 animals which gave me this: mydf <- head(irpig,n=25)
mydf$anim <- as.factor(mydf$anim)
mydf$point <- as.factor(mydf$point)
levels(mydf$point)  =c("bel","ber","le","re","ey","cr")
library(reshape2)
dcast(mydf, anim ~ point)

   anim  bel  ber   le   re   ey
1 20584 37.9 37.7 34.3 35.8 37.6
2 20585   NA 38.7   NA 36.4 38.0
3 20586 39.0 39.8 37.9 38.0 38.5
4 20587 39.3 38.9 39.4 38.6 39.4
5 20588 39.6 39.2 38.9 38.0 39.6
6 20589 38.1 38.7   NA   NA   NA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one solution. It uses the `dcast` function from `reshape2` library by Hadley Wickham

```
mydf$point = as.factor(mydf$point)
levels(mydf$point)  = c("bel", "ber", "le", "re",  "ey", "cr")

library(reshape2)
dcast(mydf, anim ~ point)

  anim  bel  ber   le   re ey   cr
1    1 38.8 38.5 33.2 33.5 NA 37.2
2    2   NA   NA 36.2 36.5 36 37.8
```

Comment: It works for the sample question above but its giving me this error message when applied to my dataset "Error in `*tmp*`$mespoint : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors"

Comment: @baz can you do a `dput` of your dataset or a subset of it. that would help debug your error message

Comment: I have just added under my original question the extract of the first 25 animals from my data set.

Comment: @baz. i tried the code on your data and it works perfectly. so am not sure what's going wrong for you.

Comment: I got this when using the whole data set:                 anim bel ber le re ey cr
1   20569   1   1  1  1  0  1
2   20570   1   1  1  1  0  1
3   20571   1   1  1  1  0  1